# SQL - Start and End date based on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Simplified structure.

I need the two dates between a record that has an action type of 4 and an action type of 1.

The record could be in that state multiple times and I would need separate rows for their times

For example for IncidentId = 1

- Row 1 - StartTime = 2017-01-01 14:00 (id:3) - End Time = 2017-01-01 20:00 (id: 5)
- Row 2 - StartTime = 2017-01-01 21:00 (id:6) - End Time = 2017-01-02 11:00 (id: 9)

```
    CREATE TABLE #returntable 
      ( 
         [incidentid] INT, 
         [starttime]  DATETIME, 
         [endtime]    DATETIME 
      ) 

    CREATE TABLE #testtableofdoom 
      ( 
         [incidentlogid] INT, 
         [incidentid]    INT, 
         [timestamp]     DATETIME, 
         [actiontypeid]  INT 
      ) 

     INSERT INTO #testtableofdoom
            ( incidentlogid, incidentid, timestamp, actiontypeid )
     VALUES ( 1, 1, '2017-01-01 09:00', 1 )
        ,   ( 2, 1, '2017-01-01 11:00', 1 )
        ,   ( 3, 1, '2017-01-01 14:00', 4 )
        ,   ( 4, 1, '2017-01-01 16:00', 4 )
        ,   ( 5, 1, '2017-01-01 20:00', 1 )
        ,   ( 6, 1, '2017-01-01 21:00', 4 )
        ,   ( 7, 1, '2017-01-02 09:00', 4 )
        ,   ( 8, 2, '2017-01-02 10:00', 1 )
        ,   ( 9, 1, '2017-01-02 11:00', 1 )
        ,   ( 10, 1, '2017-01-02 14:00', 1 )
        ,   ( 11, 2, '2017-01-02 15:00', 4 )
        ,   ( 12, 1, '2017-01-02 16:00', 1 )    
        ,   ( 13, 1, '2017-01-02 17:00', 1 )
        ,   ( 14, 1, '2017-01-02 18:00', 1 )
        ,   ( 15, 2, '2017-01-02 15:00', 1 );

    DROP TABLE #testtableofdoom 

    DROP TABLE #returntable
```

Comment: How do you know which `StartTime` (4) goes with which `EndTime` (1)? For example: `IncidentLogID`s #6 & #7 both indicate a start for `IncidentID` #1.  How do you know if `IncidentLogID` #8 is paired with #6 or #7?

Comment: It's how the data is formatted. When an incident is OnHold it stays at ActionTypeId of 4. It stays like this until it's no longer on hold, but other fields could change without the 4 changing. The middle records for example row id 7 - can be ignored in terms of returning the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used table variables instead of temp tables, and shorter column names than you, but this works:

```
declare @tt TABLE ( 
     logId INT, iId INT, 
     dt DATETIME, atId  INT  

INSERT @tt (logId, iId, 
    dt, atId) values 
(1, 1, '2017-01-01 09:00', 1),
(2, 1, '2017-01-01 11:00', 1),
(3, 1, '2017-01-01 14:00', 4),
(4, 1, '2017-01-01 16:00', 4),
(5, 1, '2017-01-01 20:00', 1),
(6, 1, '2017-01-01 21:00', 4),
(7, 1, '2017-01-02 09:00', 4),
(8, 2, '2017-01-02 10:00', 1),
(9, 1, '2017-01-02 11:00', 1),
(10, 1, '2017-01-02 14:00', 1),
(11, 2, '2017-01-02 15:00', 4),
(12, 1, '2017-01-02 16:00', 1),
(13, 1, '2017-01-02 17:00', 1),
(14, 1, '2017-01-02 18:00', 1),
(15, 2, '2017-01-02 15:00', 1)

Select s.logId startLogid, e.logId endLogId, 
       s.iID, s.dt startTime, e.dt endTime 
from @tt s join @tt e
    on e.logId = 
       (Select min(logId) from @tt
        where iId = s.iID
            and atId = 1
            and logId > s.logId)                
where s.aTid = 4 
      and ((Select atId from @tt
            Where logId = 
               (Select Max(logId) from @tt
                where logId < s.LogId 
                 and iId = s.iId)) = 1
        or Not Exists 
           (Select * from @tt
            Where logId < s.LogId 
              and iId = s.iID))
```

This produces the following:

```
 startLogid  endLogId    iID  startTime               endTime
 ----------- ----------- ---- ----------------   ----------------
     3           5        1   2017-01-01 14:00   2017-01-01 20:00
     6           9        1   2017-01-01 21:00   2017-01-02 11:00
    11          15        2   2017-01-02 15:00   2017-01-02 15:00
```

it uses a self-join. `s` represents the first (start) record with actionType 4, and `e` represents end record with action type 1.   Since `logId` increments, the end record must have higher `logId` than the start record, and it must be the lowest `logId` higher than the start records that has same `iId` and an `atId` = 1.

```
Select s.iID, s.dt startTime, e.dt endTime 
from @tt s join @tt e
    on e.logId = 
       (Select min(logId) from @tt    -- lowest log greater than start logId
        where iId = s.iID         -- same iId
            and atId = 1          -- with atId = 1
            and logId > s.logId) -- greater than start logId
```

finally, the start record must be restricted to those "4" records which either have no other same incident records before it or have a "1" record immediately prior to it.

```
where s.aTid = 4 
      and ((Select atId from @tt            -- atId of immed prior = 1
            Where logId = 
               (Select Max(logId) from @tt
                where logId < s.LogId 
                 and iId = s.iId)) = 1
        or Not Exists                       -- or there is no prior record
           (Select * from @tt
            Where logId < s.LogId 
              and iId = s.iID))
```

Comment: Afraid no luck - it gets the first instance of them for incident 1, however doesn't get it for the second one. Overall the query should return three rows rather than two. Incident 1 goes back on hold on row 6 to 8 as well as rows 3 to 5. Cheers

Comment: But row 8 is for incidentId = 2.  And what about IncidentId 2 from row 11 to row 15?

Comment: Incident 1 goes back on hold on row 6 and then off hold on row 9. Typo. The query below returns the information required - when inside a cursor. Ideally I'd like to not have a cursor, but if that's what it takes, I'll go down that route.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
select 
d.[timestamp] as StartDate, 
(select top 1 [timestamp] 
 from #testTableOfDoom d2 
 where d2.incidentid = 1 and d2.[timestamp] > d.[timestamp] and actiontypeid = 1 
 order by d2.[timestamp] asc
) as EndDate
from
    (select 
    p.[timestamp],
    LAG(p.actiontypeid) OVER (ORDER BY incidentlogid asc) PrevValue,
    p.actiontypeid 
    from #testTableOfDoom p
    where p.incidentid = 1) d
where d.actiontypeid = 4 
and d.PrevValue <> 4
```